# Rotate in FULLSCREEN mode in iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I used this bellow code to set orientation for my app. But it only works on iOS 6 and 7, it cannot work on ios 5.

```
    - (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    BOOL result = [completeTab getValue];
    if (result) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

}
```

How can i support it for iOS 5? I tried debug on above function, if I run on Simulator ios 6 and 7, this function is called, but when u run on Simulator ios 5, this functions isn't called. Please give me any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this for IOS 5....**[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];**

Comment: iOS 5 (and earlier) use a whole different set of methods for orientations. The method you posted was added in iOS 6.0. I suggest you load the iOS 5 documentation in Xcode and find the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" and look into how orientations are handled with iOS 5.